# Scan for available Wi-Fi networks on BlackBerry

Tags: networking, blackberry, wifi, gprs

Is there any [RIM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Research_In_Motion) API available which will help to get the list of available network service or only Wi-Fi networks for a device and set selected network access point for any network communications?

Is it possible for my application to disable the mobile networks like GPRS, WAP, etc.?

Example:
When the application is started it should scan for Wi-Fi connections, even if there are no previous Wi-Fi network access points set on the device, and list the available Wi-Fi connections.  Then the user will select the appropriate Wi-Fi connection to connect for any network communication. Outside the application any Internet communication, like the browser or any other application, should be done through the same selected Wi-Fi connection. 
The scanning for Wi-Fi and setting the connection is almost similar to BlackBerry Wi-Fi Setup.

I am looking to do this for BlackBerry OS 4.5, 4.7 and 5.0.

**Update**

The thing is I'm looking for Wi-Fi scanning through application. It's like through the application I am able to scan available Wi-Fi access points or hotspots and set one of access point by selecting it to device, then connect to it for communication.

Basically it's like, how do we set the Wi-Fi connection in "Manage connetion" of BlackBerry?  I have to do a similar thing through the applicaiton.

From some BlackBerry forums I got to know there is package in OS v5.0, that is, a **net.rim.device.api.wlan.hotspot** package to get the Wi-Fi hotspots. But after a long search I didn't find any sample example or much explanation on it. As I am trying to implement by looking into its API documentation, but I did not succeded.

If you have any idea related to this or any sample code it will be very helpful.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am looking for example code on the hotspot classes and am struggling to find any.

Answer (score 5):

Well, to scan for all available networks for the application you can use the [NetworkDiagnostic tool](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800451/800563/What_Is_-_Network_Diagnostic_Tool.html?nodeid=1450596&vernum=0) from RIM.

Anther piece of code to scan for your phone connectivity and get the best connection string can be found in *[How to reliably establish a network connection on any BlackBerry device](http://www.localytics.com/blog/post/how-to-reliably-establish-a-network-connection-on-any-blackberry-device)*,

```
/**
 * Determines what connection type to use and returns the necessary string to use it.
 * @return A string with the connection info
 */
private static String getConnectionString()
{
    // This code is based on the connection code developed by Mike Nelson of AccelGolf.
    // http://blog.accelgolf.com/2009/05/22/blackberry-cross-carrier-and-cross-network-http-connection
    String connectionString = null;

    // Simulator behavior is controlled by the USE_MDS_IN_SIMULATOR variable.
    if (DeviceInfo.isSimulator())
    {
            if (UploaderThread.USE_MDS_IN_SIMULATOR)
            {
                    logMessage("Device is a simulator and USE_MDS_IN_SIMULATOR is true");
                    connectionString = ";deviceside=false";
            }
            else
            {
                    logMessage("Device is a simulator and USE_MDS_IN_SIMULATOR is false");
                    connectionString = ";deviceside=true";
            }
    }

    // Wi-Fi is the preferred transmission method.
    else if (WLANInfo.getWLANState() == WLANInfo.WLAN_STATE_CONNECTED)
    {
        logMessage("Device is connected via Wifi.");
        connectionString = ";interface=wifi";
    }

    // Is the carrier network the only way to connect?
    else if ((CoverageInfo.getCoverageStatus() & CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_DIRECT) == CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_DIRECT)
    {
        logMessage("Carrier coverage.");

        String carrierUid = getCarrierBIBSUid();
        if (carrierUid == null)
        {
            // Has carrier coverage, but not BIBS.  So use the carrier's TCP network
            logMessage("No Uid");
            connectionString = ";deviceside=true";
        }
        else
        {
            // otherwise, use the Uid to construct a valid carrier BIBS request
            logMessage("uid is: " + carrierUid);
            connectionString = ";deviceside=false;connectionUID="+carrierUid + ";ConnectionType=mds-public";
        }
    }

    // Check for an MDS connection instead (BlackBerry Enterprise Server).
    else if ((CoverageInfo.getCoverageStatus() & CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_MDS) == CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_MDS)
    {
        logMessage("MDS coverage found");
        connectionString = ";deviceside=false";
    }

    // If there is no connection available abort to avoid bugging the user unnecssarily.
    else if (CoverageInfo.getCoverageStatus() == CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_NONE)
    {
        logMessage("There is no available connection.");
    }

    // In theory, all bases are covered so this shouldn't be reachable.
    else
    {
        logMessage("no other options found, assuming device.");
        connectionString = ";deviceside=true";
    }

    return connectionString;
}

/**
 * Looks through the phone's service book for a carrier provided BIBS network
 * @return The uid used to connect to that network.
 */
private static String getCarrierBIBSUid()
{
    ServiceRecord[] records = ServiceBook.getSB().getRecords();
    int currentRecord;

    for (currentRecord = 0; currentRecord < records.length; currentRecord++)
    {
        if (records[currentRecord].getCid().toLowerCase().equals("ippp"))
        {
            if (records[currentRecord].getName().toLowerCase().indexOf("bibs") >= 0)
            {
                return records[currentRecord].getUid();
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I ran that RIM NetworkDiagnosticTool, and it doesn't seem to provide any list of the multiple WiFi networks available.  I also inspected the source code, and didn't see anything in there collecting (but not displaying) that information.