# List WiFi access points

Tags: blackberry

I am creating an application which lists the available WiFi connections. Then user can select the appropriate WiFi connection for any network communication.

I saw plenty of links but nothing is useful. One says that using the HotspotClient class can get available networks. But I can't find any useful methods in that class.

I used following links

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/How-to-scan-for-available-networks-for-device-from-application/m-p/519179/highlight/false#M105143

[Scan for available Wi-Fi networks on BlackBerry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992052/how-to-scan-for-available-networks-for-blackberry-device-from-application)

Comment: Honestly, the second link looks like an exact duplicate of this question.

Comment: Were you able to figure it out? Even I am facing the same problem now.