# Blackberry API - WLANInfo.WLANAPInfo

Tags: blackberry, wifi

Development environment:

```
- Device: Blackberry Storm2
- IDE: Eclipse Galileo, BB Plugin
- Reference API: 6.0
```

I am trying to scan all possible WiFi Access Points on a 1 minute period directly from my App but I do not want to -connect, authenticate, or add - any of those Access Point to any instance of my application or the device itself. I only want to read some sort of "Vector" with the information (BSID, etc) of the Access Points founded.

I have read for specific issue and there are a couple of posts that haven't been of any help:
- [Scan for available Wi-Fi networks on BlackBerry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992052/scan-for-available-wifi-networks-on-blackberry)
- [List WiFi access points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036747/list-wifi-access-points)

I would really appreciate any help on this issue, I have tried to use:
- HotspotClient Class

But I have not succeed because I am not quite sure how to work with that class (knowing that its an abstract class)

The last I found is the

> WLANInfo.WLANAPInfo

Class and I think it may be useful for my purpose... Any suggestion on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I agree that using Hotspots Clients is not very convenient, requiring the user accept it out of the applicaiton. I haven't found a solution to this but you can build a (poor) list of wi-fi's by hooking up a WLANConnectionListener:

WLANInfo.addListener(someWLANConnectionListerner);

Then you can use the listener to log the ssid and other info of the networks the device connects to:

void networkConnected() {
    AppMain.LogEvent("wLanListener: Network Connected.");
    info = WLANInfo.getAPInfo();
    }

Pretty lame, I know. Any other ideas?