# How to programmatically Scan available wifi networks in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

Is there any way to get all available wifi networks on thirdparty application.
After doing a lot off googling i got codes that do this but after installing the app user need to do mannual setting..
I have no need of this.

I wants when i install my app its only show the available(SSID) networks without any settings.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scan for available Wi-Fi networks on BlackBerry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992052/scan-for-available-wi-fi-networks-on-blackberry)

Comment: see [Search for Available Transports on the Device](http://testberry.blogspot.com/2011/05/blackberry-connectivity-issues.html)

Answer (score -1):

//use following function

```
 public boolean isWiFiEnable()
    {
        if( WLANInfo.getWLANState() == WLANInfo.WLAN_STATE_CONNECTED )
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Hrushikesh Salkade for your response,but thats not my question.   This method is for to check the connectivity status.........                     I want to get the list of available wifi networks in range programmatically ,without any mannual setting through user.

Comment: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Scanning-wifi-network-in-app/td-p/1676063 this may help you